# Get the fully qualified name of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net

All, I have a log4net implementation and I'm trying to use the `AdoNetAppender`, but one of the subelements for the `appender` configuration is `connectionType` and it requires a fully qualified class name like `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` (got that from the documentation as an example).

However, it can't load that one because this is a .NET4 MVC application. Can somebody tell me how I can get that fully qualified name so it will load the type and connect to the database? I've tried everything that I can honestly think of.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'm not sure what type you need, but you can use this in code to get the fully qualified name of a type.

```
string fullyQualifiedName = typeof(MyType).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Comment: This effectively ended up being the best I could do. I did finally find another way as well, when the application loads, the output window lists all of the loaded assemblies fully qualified name, you can copy it from there as well (though not directly cause it's in a different format).

Comment: Is there away of obtaining this at compile time?  I wish nameof() could,help.

Comment: In my case this worked for me. typeof(string).UnderlyingSystemType.FullName

Comment: Yes, if you only need the namespace + class name, use Dblock247's suggestion of FullName instead of AssemblyQualifiedName