# Get the fully qualified name of a class in compiling environment?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

In many situations I need the full name of a class, to use it to run commands in PMC like specifying the `-ContextTypeName` in EF migrations, is there a fast way to get it, rather tracking where it lives- the hard way?

**EDIT**

I apparently didn't mean something like this:

```
string fullyQualifiedName = typeof(MyType).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

I need something that Visual Studio may come with as a tool or extension that enable me copying the full name from the context menu of the class identifier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the fully qualified name of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204720/get-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-class)

Comment: Have you read my question and the answer there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery has lead me this extension: [Copy Qualified Name for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f15022a5-aec4-44e7-a51d-6c24df3b55e0) which appears to possibly do what you are after.

Once installed, right click on a class name and select `Copy qualified name` option from the context, and the qualified name of the class will be copied to the clipboard.